# EF table splitting with table AspNetUsers

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I use two classes.

```
public partial class User
{
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public ICollection<IntRole> Roles { get; set; }

        public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}

public partial class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int, IntUserLogin, IntUserRole, IntUserClaim>
{
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

I want to map both classes to table AspNetUsers.
I configured all fields in this table to make them optional.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasOptional(a => a.User).WithMany().HasForeignKey(a => a.Id);
            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasRequired(a => a.User).WithRequiredDependent(s => s.ApplicationUser);
            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().Property(a => a.EmailConfirmed).IsOptional();
            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().Property(a => a.PhoneNumber).IsOptional();
            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().Property(a => a.PhoneNumberConfirmed).IsOptional();
            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().Property(a => a.TwoFactorEnabled).IsOptional();
            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().Property(a => a.LockoutEnabled).IsOptional();
            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().Property(a => a.AccessFailedCount).IsOptional();
            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().Property(a => a.UserName).IsOptional();

            modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("AspNetUsers");
        }
```

I make automatic migration and the result is successful.
When I want to add single User  defined by class User in controller.

```
context.SpecialUser.Add(new Models.User { FirstName = "Halo", LastName = "Halo2" });
context.SaveChanges();
```

I got the following info.
**Invalid data encountered. A required relationship is missing. Examine StateEntries to determine the source of the constraint violation.**

What relationship should I define?
Result of InnerException.
[image]

Comment: What are the contents of StateEntries in the thrown exception?

Comment: @Matt I have posted thrown expection.